# Change Moodle Activity Plugin to Resource Plugin

Tags: moodle

I wanted to develop new Moodle resource module.  I have developed my module as activity module and it works fine. Now I want to change it to resource module. What are the changes do I have to make ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
You have to add following line inside the "supports" function in 'lib.php'.

"case FEATURE_MOD_ARCHETYPE: return MOD_ARCHETYPE_RESOURCE;"